# convert zip codes to latitude and longitude

Tags: spatial

I have a data set that includes a list of zip codes. Is there a way in R to convert these zip codes to latitude and longitude coordinates?

Thanks!

Comment: This probably belongs on http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the `geocode` function in the `ggmap` package.

Comment: will this allow zip+4 or does it only use zip centroids?

Comment: It's using Google Maps, so works however Google would. (Only get a limited number of geocodes per day.)